# Reading data from a file in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm currently trying to read the data in fairly easy structured file, but I can't seem to get the right result . On the first line of the file is a single value `n`, then on the next `n*n` lines the entries of a square matrix .

How can I store the first value in an one-cell matrix, then the rest of it in a different one ?

The file looks like this :

**input.txt**

```
17
5 7 9 5 8 8 6 4 4 6 7 7 8 7 5 5 6
8 8 4 3 0 6 3 0 8 2 5 1 1 9 2 1 5
2 5 9 3 0 6 9 6 8 3 9 6 7 9 2 8 1
2 8 8 6 4 7 5 9 0 0 6 5 9 1 3 0 6
3 9 7 1 9 3 3 7 4 6 6 7 2 0 8 6 9
1 0 3 3 5 8 9 2 1 5 5 2 9 7 4 9 0
2 1 8 8 9 8 4 7 2 2 9 0 0 8 2 3 5
1 0 4 1 4 0 1 9 6 4 6 5 7 3 8 1 5
2 2 1 4 7 7 5 2 7 4 0 3 0 1 6 3 8
3 7 4 0 0 8 7 7 2 4 2 9 9 1 2 2 3
2 0 3 9 1 3 8 6 9 4 1 7 6 4 0 2 5
9 4 3 9 0 9 8 7 0 5 5 0 6 0 0 2 8
9 4 9 9 3 4 9 1 1 4 0 3 4 5 4 9 1
1 3 5 6 4 1 7 6 7 0 5 4 4 7 1 2 4
7 0 2 4 1 9 5 3 2 4 1 5 4 0 3 8 9
9 8 8 7 3 4 7 8 5 9 2 6 3 3 5 7 5
1 4 5 8 5 3 0 5 3 4 1 9 0 7 1 4 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
x = importdata('input.txt');
n = x(1); %// matrix size
M = redshape(x(2:end),n,n).'; %'// matrix
```

Comment: with this, I get  `error: reshape: can't reshape 1x305 array to 17x17 array`

Comment: There is no error with the example input file in the question. You must be using a different number of values. Note that 305 is not a perfect square

Answer (score 2):

Try this (I think it is more optimal than using importdata):

```
X = dlmread('input.txt',' ',0);
n = X(1,1); %// matrix size; make sure that there is no space before your 17
nn = X(2:end,:);
```

Comment: Beat me by 7 seconds! I would avoid using input as it's a Matlab function however.

Comment: Good alternative to `importdata`!

Comment: I tested my code and it works correctly (even with a var named input) ^_^

Comment: @MohammedGh Yes, it works, but shadowing a function for no reason is not cosidered good practice. Better to change that variable name

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using `dlmread`

```
raw = dlmread('input.txt');
a = num2cell(raw(1,1));
b = num2cell(raw(2:end,:));
```